# Preventing Sign Extension with Byte Mask

Tags: java, networking, arrays, endianness

I've been reading the book TCP/IP Sockets in Java, 2nd Edition. I was hoping to get more clarity on something, but since the book's website doesn't having a forum or anything, I thought I'd ask here.
In several places, the book uses a byte mask to avoid sign extension. Here's an example:

```
private final static int BYTEMASK = 0xFF; //8 bits

public static long decodeIntBigEndian(byte[] val, int offset, int size) {
    long rtn = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        rtn = (rtn << Byte.SIZE) | ((long) val[offset + i] & BYTEMASK);
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

So here's my guess of what's going on. Let me know if I'm right.
`BYTEMASK` in binary should look like `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`.
To make things easy, let's just say the `val` byte array only contains 1 short so the offset is 0. So let's set the byte array to `val[0] = 11111111`, `val[1] = 00001111`. At `i = 0`, `rtn` is all 0's so `rtn << Byte.SIZE` just keeps the value the same. Then there's `(long)val[0]` making it 8 bytes with all 1's due to sign extension. But when you use `& BYTEMASK`, it sets all those extra 1's to 0's, leaving that last byte all 1's. Then you get `rtn | val[0]` which basically flips on any 1's in the last byte of `rtn`. For `i = 1`, `(rtn << Byte.SIZE)` pushes the least-significant byte over and leaves all 0's in place. Then `(long)val[1]` makes a long with all zero's plus `00001111` for the least-significant byte which is what we want. So using `& BYTEMASK` doesn't change it. Then when `rtn | val[1]` is used, it flips `rtn`'s least-significant byte to all 1's. The final return value is now `rtn = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 11111111`.
So, I hope this wasn't too long, and it was understandable. I just want to know if the way I'm thinking about this is correct, and not just completely wacked out logic. Also, one thing that confuses me is the `BYTEMASK` is `0xFF`. In binary, this would be `11111111 11111111`, so if it's being implicitly cast to an int, wouldn't it actually be `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` due to sign-extension? If that's the case, then it doesn't make sense to me how `BYTEMASK` would even work. Thank you for reading.

Comment: `0xFF` is an int, why would it be sign-extended? And in binary it would be `11111111`.

Comment: At a glance, this post looks uncannily similar to infamous 'XHTML with regex' post...

Comment: Can you guys be a little less condescending?

Comment: Even though it seems you've got the answer, one correction to your question text: `0xFF` != `11111111 11111111` but just `11111111`.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm not sure why I wrote that. Must have had a brain fart with writing all those 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything is right except for the last point:

`0xFF` is already an `int` (`0x000000FF`), so it won't be sign-extended. In general, [integer number literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) in Java are `int`s unless they end with an `L` or `l` and then they are `long`s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1 to you if I had enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @elveatles *Accept* the answer. That's something you should do anyway and you'll also get some rep for doing it. Click the checkmark to the left of the answer.